# Update Values Returned from Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql query that returns all duplicates (except most recent).

```
select *
from CodeData
inner join 
    (select max(cdID) as lastId, cdName
     from CodeData
     where cdName in (select cdName from CodeData
                      group by cdName
                      having count(*) > 1)
     group by cdName) duplic on duplic.cdName = CodeData.cdName
where CodeData.cdID < duplic.lastId;
```

How would I go about updating a column for each result returned in the above query? Say I have an arbitrary column `A`, I was thinking about something along the lines of this at the end of the query.

```
update CodeData 
set A = 0 
where CodeData.cdID < CodeData.duplic.lastId;
```

But this ends up updating the entire table, and not just the returned results above.

Any tips?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cdName order by cdId desc) as seqnum
      from codedata cd
     ) 
update toupdate
    set a = 0
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Note:  You might find that `row_number()` is sufficient to handle the "duplication" issue and you don't need to store an additional column at all.

And you might really want:

```
update toupdate
    set a = (case when seqnum > 1 then 0 else 1 end);
```

Comment: The above statements do not compile and give me syntax error:
`Incorrect syntax near 'partition'. Expecting  '(', or SELECT.`

Comment: @MaxB . . . This db<>fiddle shows that the code compiles:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09ed1a34b9c15ab8a9f976255d9be671.

Comment: Interesting.... my slightly reworked seems to have issues: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9152c82c2a8d03e4eb83837c7f10e6b5

Comment: @MaxB . . . Put in a comma after the `*`.

Comment: oh doh.... still seem to have on small headache in there though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69c2db9b15884884ba9d5bea24ed02d1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f19ad9519a7a096c87cac14ba3d1077b